# Powershell ImportExcel fails on duplicate column headers

Tags: excel

I'm using ImportExcel to pull data from SQL server into Excel and then split the resulting file in several smaller if they are over a certain size. I'm using Open-ExcelPackage to keep the original file open in order to improve performance.
But Import-Excel is complaining about duplicate headers when I start the 2nd file.

Code and Exception below - Any 2 Cents welcome!
Also if there's a better way of doing this without using Excel I'm all ears!!

````
Send-SQLDataToExcel -MsSqlServer -Connection "our-sql-01" -DataBase our_db -QueryTimeOut 500 -SQL "[dbo].[PitProductCostingBranchPrices] 0,NULL,1" -NoNumberConversion BranchCode -WorkSheetName "Branch Prices" -Path c:\tmp\test.xlsx

get-date


$xlPkg = Open-ExcelPackage -Path c:\tmp\test.xlsx
Get-Date

$totRows = $xlPkg.'Branch Prices'.Dimension.Rows
$maxRows = 50000
$firstRow = 1
$lastRow = $maxRows
$fNum = 1
while($lastRow -le $totRows) {
$firstRow
$lastRow
$fNum
    $rows = Import-Excel -ExcelPackage $xlPkg -WorksheetName "Branch Prices" -StartRow $firstRow -EndRow $lastRow
    Get-Date
    $rows | Export-Excel -Path C:\tmp\test_1_$fNum.xlsx -NoNumberConversion BranchCode -WorkSheetName "Branch Prices" 
    Get-Date
    $firstRow += $maxRows
    $lastRow += $maxRows
    $fNum++
    
}

get-date

*Output & Exception below:*

Close-ExcelPackage $xlPkg
get-date```

Tuesday, August 1, 2023 6:26:19 AM
Tuesday, August 1, 2023 6:26:19 AM
Tuesday, August 1, 2023 6:26:31 AM
1
50000
1
Tuesday, August 1, 2023 6:28:44 AM
Tuesday, August 1, 2023 6:29:06 AM
50001
100000
2
Failed importing the Excel workbook '' with worksheet 'Branch Prices': Duplicate column headers found on row '50001' in columns '4 11 14 5 8 12 6 7 9 10'. Column headers must be unique, if this is not a 
requirement please use the '-NoHeader' or '-HeaderName' parameter.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.8.4\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:244 char:21
+ ...     catch { throw "Failed importing the Excel workbook '$Path' with w ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Failed importin...ame' parameter.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed importing the Excel workbook '' with worksheet 'Branch Prices': Duplicate column headers found on row '50001' in columns '4 11 14 5 8 12 6 7 9 10'. Column headers mus 
   t be unique, if this is not a requirement please use the '-NoHeader' or '-HeaderName' parameter.
````

Comment: What would be awesome is if you could is if you could call Export-Excel and pass in an ExcelPackage and export just a portion of if. Afaik, you can't now, you have to export the whole package.